# CListCtrl did not show text immediately like StaticText

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a code like this to write install log to a static text and a list control, and i have a button to start the installer that be handle by function `OnClickInstallBtn()` but every time I call the `WriteLogtoScreen()`, only the static text change and nothing show up in the list until the `OnClickInstallBtn()` is done and everything on that list show up all at one.

How can i make it show up right away like the static text?

```
WriteLogtoScreen(LPCTSTR sLog)
{
    int         iItems;
    iItems = m_ListLog.GetItemCount();

    m_ListLog.InsertItem(iItems, sLog);
    m_ListLog.Update(iItems);
    m_ListLog.SetItemText(iItems, 0, sLog);
    m_ListLog.Update(iItems);
    UpdateData(FALSE);

    SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC, sLog);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem: you modify the static text and listctrl values in the same function ```WriteLogtoScreen```, why you say *... nothing show up in the list until the OnClickInstallBtn() is done ...*  ?

Comment: The static changing as i expect, after calling the SetDlgItemText, but the list control is empty, nothing more than a white box there until the OnClickInstallBtn function is done and all the logs show up at once

Comment: Don't block your UI thread. A message handler is not the place to perform lengthy operations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `RedrawWindow()` if you want to force the redraw of your list explicitly in something like this :

```
    void WriteLogtoScreen(LPCTSTR sLog)  
    {
            int      iItems;
            iItems = m_ListLog.GetItemCount();

            m_ListLog.InsertItem(iItems, sLog);
            m_ListLog.Update(iItems);
            m_ListLog.SetItemText(iItems, 0, sLog);
            m_ListLog.Update(iItems);
            UpdateData(FALSE);

            //instant redraw  
            m_ListLog.RedrawWindow();

            SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC, sLog);  
    }
```

Comment: Have you actually tested this? According to the Microsoft website the `CListCtrl` does not have this method. It has `RedrawItems` though. The `CWnd` class has `RedrawWindow` but it takes parameters. Personally I use the `CDialog::UpdateWindow` instead to re-draw the window and bypass the queue.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, I tested it. ```CListCtrl``` is declared as ```class CListCtrl : public CWnd``` (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=msvc-170). Thanks for your remark.,

Comment: This is the right answer to my problem, ty so much, actually, i test @AndrewTruckle 's solution and it's work too, but i think `RedrawWindow()` is better than `CDialog::UpdateWindow` cause it only redraw the list, not the whole program's window, am i right?

Comment: @HuyAnh I believe so.

Comment: @HuyAnh Andrew Truckle are right. The repaint will be applyed only on your CtrlList. This will not propagate a repaint on all your application/dialog